# newChooseAccountIntent returns a Name but getToken needs an Email

Tags: android, google-play-services

I started with the new Google Play Services and tried to use the information I found in the [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) and in the referenced example to create a full working app. IMHO there's something missing in these examples.

The new standard AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent can be used to select a Google Account registered on a device. Using that dialog returns the name of the account on return.

Now the examples show how to get a token. The new GoogleAuthUtil.getToken method needs an email to fetch the token.

There's something missing. How can I get the email from a given account name?

Many thanks in advance.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String AUTHTOKENSCOPE_DRIVE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

    String accountName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    // Need to fetch token with email
                    // String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, <???email???>,  
                           AUTHTOKENSCOPE_DRIVE);
                } else {
                }

                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int rc = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        switch (rc) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] {
                        "com.google"
                },
                        true, null, AUTHTOKENSCOPE_DRIVE, new String[] {
                            "Just a text"
                        }, null);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Google accounts, the email address **is** the account name.

So this should work for you:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, accountName, AUTHTOKENSCOPE_DRIVE);
```

To recheck, that there's an `Account` object available for this `accountName` you can also call

```
GoogleAccountManager accountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(context);
Account account = accountManager.getAccountByName(accountName);
```

**Proofs**

From the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) you already referenced:

> Second, you don’t need an android.accounts.Account object, you just use the email-address string (**available in account.name**) that uniquely identifies it.

From Google's [Calendar API sample application for Android](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-preview-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/CalendarSampleActivity.java?repo=samples&r=549a58c4b30b111c5f868b73e877a679be48e897), the [`GoogleAccountCredential.getAccountName()`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-preview-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/GoogleAccountCredential.java?repo=samples&r=549a58c4b30b111c5f868b73e877a679be48e897) method:

```
/**
 * Returns the selected Google account name (e-mail address), for example
 * {@code "johndoe@gmail.com"}, or {@code null} for none.
 */
public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}
```

There they also use:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, scope);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was quit confusing for me that the not working example (Activity without onCreate) was using accountName and email in the same code blog without showing where email comes from.